# From a letter to a precious item

Tags: wordplay

> Start with a square letter.
>   Add one more letter and I am practically everywhere.
>   Do that again, I am a crop.
>   Repeat, I am a fruit.
>   Once more and I become valuable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer:

> **P** = 16th letter of the alphabet, 16 is the square of 4
>  **PE** = **P**ractically **E**verywhere (actual intended meaning: **P**oly**e**thylene)
>  **PEA** = crop
>  **PEAR** = fruit
>  **PEARL** = valuable

Comment: This is the right answer, however, my intention on the second step was a bit different. Didn't even notice this works as well. :)

Comment: Thanks. I honestly couldn't figure out any other solution to the second line, or I'd have given that instead.

Comment: The second is actually (rot13) nooerivngvba sbe n pbzzba cynfgvp - cbylrgulyrar.

Comment: Ah, I see. I was about to ask. Added it to the accepted answer.